# What is the best way to handle "a single element or an array" JSON property in Go?

Tags: json, api, go

Now we have a JSON HTTP request data which would be a single element like
`{"data": {"id":1}}` OR an array of elements like `{"data": [{"id":1}, {"id":2}]}`.

Since a client side cannot change the implementation, we have to keep and accept this data structure.

Currently I implement struct like:

```
type Request struct {
  rawData json.RawMessage `json:"data"`

  Data *Data `json:"-"`
  DataList []*Data `json:"-"`
}
```

And first parse "data" property as json.RawMessage into variable `req`, try parsing as a single element first, then if it fails try parsing as an array.

```
if err := json.Unmarshal(req.rawData, &req.Data); err != nil {
    if err := json.Unmarshal(req.RawData, &req.DataList); err != nil {
        return errors.New("could not parse data")
    } else if len(req.DataList) < 1 {
        return errors.New("empty list")
    }
}
```

In this case, later when we want to use this data, we can check if `rawData` is a single element or an array by `len(req.Datalist) >= 1`. (Or I can set some flag to show that like `isDataMultiple` in the struct, when parsing).

Is there any idiomatic way to achieve the same result in Go other than what I'm doing?

Comment: I personally would just make the value an array. You can have an array of length one.

Comment: Your example that tries to unmarshal a singleton and then attempts to do it as an array if it fails is the most idiomatic way to handle this in Go.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32346117/unmarshalling-a-json-that-may-or-may-not-return-an-array), [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37152092/what-is-a-good-way-to-handle-single-or-array-struct-in-golang-json-unmarshal), [three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33622016/json-sometimes-array-sometimes-object), [four](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33569210/go-json-unmarshal-options).

Comment: >squiguy I see, I like that idea:)  

>evanmcdonnal, >icza
Yeah I know there are some related questions and I wanted to know if there is some standardized solution for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
type Request struct {
   RawData json.RawMessage `json:"data"`  // export field for unmarshal of entire request
   DataList []*Data `json:"-"`           // always use slice
}

// Is it an array?
if bytes.HasPrefix(bytes.TrimSpace(req.RawData), []byte{'['})) {
   if err := json.Unmarshal(req.RawData, &req.DataList); err != nil {
       // handle error parsing array
   }
} else {
   var v Data
   if err := json.Unmarshal(req.RawData, &v); err != nil {
       // handle error parsing single value
   }
   req.DataList = []*Data{&v)
}
```

Comment: I see. Instead of trying to marshal into a single element, we can check the actual first byte character, `[`. Thank you for the suggestion! I like it.